# Docker exec not working: input/output error

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox, docker-exec

I use Docker Toolbox on Windows Server 2012. I have one container:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\services\ndvi-service>docker ps
CONTAINER ID IMAGE        COMMAND               CREATED    STATUS    PORTS                                           NAMES
f2e4be346df6 0ee5062e17b1 "/bin/sh -c '/src/py" 3 days ago Up 3 days 0.0.0.0:5050->5050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49555->5555/tcp vigorous_matsumoto
```

But I can't attach to that container:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\services\ndvi-service>docker exec -ti f2e4be346df6 /bin/bash
Error response from daemon: open /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4b92e20e3f62a8ea93b128eee4e86da10fb6901f3aea6308a64e31a3a5016777/lower: input/output error
```

When I started container 3 days ago the exec command works fine, but now it doesn't and I have no ideas why.

docker attach shows the same error.

There is no some resources leaks - docker stats shows 3% CPU usage and 53% Memory usage.

My service in the container works fine judging by the logs that produces my service.